# How to round some values in an object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 Array = [ {name:apples, price:3.99, tax:0.20}, 
           {name:oranges, price:1.40, tax:0.15},
           {name:bananas, price:0.99, tax:0.10}, 
         ]
```

How do I run toFixed() on all the "price" values (and not the names, for performance purposes) so that I come up with this:

```
 Array = [ {name:apples, price:4, tax:0.20}, 
           {name:oranges, price:1, tax:0.15},
           {name:bananas, price:1, tax:0.10}, 
         ]
```

Will I have to go through the loop route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop over the array (BTW: never use `Array` as a variable name):

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    arr[i].roundedPrice = Math.round(arr[i].price);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
array.forEach(function ( elem ) {
    elem.price = Math.round( elem.price );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/apSdV/

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var ixFruit = 0; ixFruit < fruits.length; ++ixFruit)
    fruits[ixFruit].price = fruits[ixFruit].price.toFixed();
```

That seems incredibly simple, not sure how you'd make it simpler.